# pm2 not starting server on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into an issue. I have deployed my nodejs websocket app to Amazon elastic beanstalk. I am trying to run app as daemon process, that's why I have globally installed `pm2` using configfile in ebextension:

container_commands:

```
01_node_symlink:    
  command: "ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/node /bin/node"
02_npm_symlink:     
  command: "ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/npm /bin/npm"   
03_pm2_install:     
  command: "if [ ! -e /bin/pm2 ]; then npm install pm2 -g; fi"
  ignoreErrors: true
```

As elastic beanstalk start server automatically, to use `pm2` I have written start command in my package.js

```
start:"pm2 start server.js -i 0 --name="hub""
```

But when elastic beanstalk uses this command to start server it goes in start-stop loop and all cpus is used.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

That's because pm2 process exits just after it starts the server, so eb run it again. add " && pm2 logs" to the command to keep it on.

Comment: You're right. I added `poststart: pm2 log` in script of package.json to solve it.